# Has there ever been a report of a helicopter flying into a downburst?

Tags: helicopter

I was recently flying my quadcopter and it started to go out of control. It was because I was flying it below a ceiling fan which acted as a mini downburst shoving the little quad to the ground.

So have there ever been reports of a helicopter accidently flying into a downburst?

Comment: Helicopters in general trade-off performance vs cost vs efficiency etc and do not have much "spare" power. A downdraft is going to result in a loss of contol in that you will not be able to maintain altitude or other axis. Helicopter pilots (and I suspect most GA pilots in general) avoid anything that might produce a downdraft. Mountain flying needs a particular set of skills and knowledge to conduct safely and knowing where downdrafts are likely to be encountered is a key part of that. Attempting to pull collective to maintain height is going to result in a loss of RRPM.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it would be really amazing if it had never happened. Since "reports" are only required in the case of accidents, here are extracts from three NTSB summaries:

**[WPR13CA155](http://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief.aspx?ev_id=20130319X81018&key=1)**

> During descent for an off-airport pinnacle landing, the helicopter
>   encountered a downdraft about 75 to 100 feet above ground level (agl),
>   and the pilot receiving instruction increased collective input. The
>   flight instructor advised the pilot receiving instruction to be less
>   aggressive using the collective as the flight continued to the landing
>   area. As the helicopter descended through about 10 to 25 feet agl, it
>   encountered a second downdraft, and the pilot receiving instruction
>   increased collective again, which was followed by a decrease in rotor
>   rpm.

**[ANC09LA098](http://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief.aspx?ev_id=20090914X80010&key=1)**

> During the approach to the 5,657 foot level site, the pilot said he
>   encountered a downdraft as the helicopter approached the site, and the
>   helicopter descended below his anticipated approach path. He initiated
>   a go-around, but the helicopter continued to descend, and landed hard,
>   about 150 feet short and down slope of his intended touchdown point.

**[WPR09CA470](http://www.ntsb.gov/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief.aspx?ev_id=20090928X05618&key=1)**

> As he flew the helicopter out of the leeward side of the peak, he
>   encountered a downdraft. He maneuvered the helicopter toward a wide
>   open valley that descended about 5,000 feet below. The downdraft
>   pushed the helicopter into the face of the mountain, despite the
>   pilot's application of full collective and descending flight into the
>   valley.

Comment: beware flying on the leeward side of a ridge

Comment: @rbp Yea, that isn't a downburst, its just flow over a mountain.

Comment: I was addressing the third example